# Spring MVC view & update

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to update data from Spring MVC's view. I could update data using tester object but failed when trying update from Spring MVC's view. POST request from view has no problem key/value were posting to server. It updated my table data but with null value (unless for id field).

Please help and thank you.

My Table (tx_surveyrequest)

```
CREATE TABLE tx_surveyrequest
(
id uuid NOT NULL,
id_person uuid,
id_surveyrequeststatus uuid,
id_validationstatus uuid,
id_employee_assistantgis uuid,
formcode character varying(64),
b_north character varying(32),
b_east character varying(32),
b_south character varying(32),
b_west character varying(32),
hectarage numeric(10,2),
is_priority boolean DEFAULT false,
requestdate date,
surveyplandate date,
surveyplantime time without time zone,
requestedby character varying(32),
requestedprice numeric(14,2),
CONSTRAINT pk_tx_surveyrequest PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My domain object (SurveyRequest)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tx_surveyrequest")
public class SurveyRequest implements Serializable {

private UUID id;
private Person person;
private String formCode;
private String borderNorth;
private String borderEast;
private String borderSouth;
private String borderWest;
private Double hectarage;
private Boolean priority;
private DateTime requestDate;
private DateTime surveyPlanDate;
private LocalTime surveyPlanTime;
private String requestedBy;
private Double requestedPrice;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
@Type(type="pg-uuid")
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "hectarage")
public Double getHectarage(){
    return hectarage;
}

public void setHectarage(Double hectarage){
    this.hectarage = hectarage;
}

@Column(name = "formcode")
public String getFormCode() {
    return formCode;
}

public void setFormCode(String formCode) {
    this.formCode = formCode;
}

@Column(name="is_priority")
public Boolean getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(Boolean priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

@Column(name="b_north")
public String getBorderNorth() {
    return borderNorth;
}

public void setBorderNorth(String border) {
    this.borderNorth = border;
}

@Column(name="b_east")
public String getBorderEast() {
    return borderEast;
}

public void setBorderEast(String border) {
    this.borderEast = border;
}

@Column(name="b_south")
public String getBorderSouth() {
    return borderSouth;
}

public void setBorderSouth(String border) {
    this.borderSouth = border;
}

@Column(name="b_west")
public String getBorderWest() {
    return borderWest;
}

public void setBorderWest(String border) {
    this.borderWest = border;
}

// TODO replace pattern with i18n
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Column(name = "requestdate")
public DateTime getRequestDate() {
    return requestDate;
}

public void setRequestDate(DateTime requestDate) {
    this.requestDate = requestDate;
}

// TODO replace pattern with i18n
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Column(name = "surveyplandate")
public DateTime getSurveyPlanDate() {
    return surveyPlanDate;
}

public void setSurveyPlanDate(DateTime surveyPlanDate) {
    this.surveyPlanDate = surveyPlanDate;
}

// TODO replace pattern with i18n
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalTimeAsTime")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
@Column(name = "surveyplantime")
public LocalTime getSurveyPlanTime() {
    return surveyPlanTime;
}

public void setSurveyPlanTime(LocalTime surveyPlanTime) {
    this.surveyPlanTime = surveyPlanTime;
}
```

Update success using SurveyRequestUpdate

```
public class SurveyRequestUpdate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("classpath:spring-data-app-context.xml");
    ctx.load("classpath:datasource.xml");
    ctx.refresh();

    SurveyRequestService surveyRequestService = ctx.getBean(
            "springJpaSurveyRequestService",SurveyRequestService.class);

    UUID uid = UUID.fromString("0cd02976-1864-447b-b540-39d6e7ee3703");     
    SurveyRequest request = surveyRequestService.findById(uid);
    System.out.println("Find by ID");
    System.out.println(request);        
    request.setSurveyPlanDate (new DateTime(2014,7,1,0,0));
    request.setSurveyPlanTime (new LocalTime(22,0));
    surveyRequestService.save(request);
    System.out.println(request);
}
```

Update Form View

```
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_list" var="labelSurveyRequestList" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_title" var="labelSurveyRequestTitle" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_code" var="labelSurveyRequestCode" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_requestdate" var="labelSurveyRequestRequestDate" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_surveydate" var="labelSurveyRequestSurveyDate" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_surveytime" var="labelSurveyRequestSurveyTime" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_priority" var="labelSurveyRequestPriority" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_complete" var="labelSurveyRequestComplete" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_hectarage" var="labelSurveyRequestHectarage" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_north" var="labelSurveyRequestNorth" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_east" var="labelSurveyRequestEast" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_south" var="labelSurveyRequestSouth" />
<spring:message code="l_surveyrequest_west" var="labelSurveyRequestWest" />

<spring:message code="form_new" var="formNew" />
<spring:message code="form_edit" var="formEdit" />  

<spring:message code="btn_save" var="buttonSave" />
<spring:message code="btn_cancel" var="buttonCancel" />

<spring:message code="long_date_format_pattern" var="formatDate" />
<spring:message code="time_format_pattern" var="formatDateTime" />
<spring:message code="short_time_format_pattern" var="formatShortTime" />

<spring:url value="/surveyrequest" var="showSurveyRequestUrl" />

<spring:eval expression="surveyRequest.id == null ? formNew:formEdit" var="formTitle"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>${formTitle} ${labelSurveyRequestTitle}</h1>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- /top action bar -->
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <c:if test="${not empty surveyRequest}">
            <form:form class="form-horizontal"
                modelAttribute="surveyRequest" commandName="surveyRequest" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">${buttonSave}</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">${buttonCancel}</button>                           
                    </div>
                </div>

                <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                     <div id="message" class="${message.type}">${message.message}</div>
                 </c:if>

                <div class="form-group">        
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">${labelSurveyRequestCode}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="formCode" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">${labelSurveyRequestRequestDate}</label>
                    <div class='col-md-3 input-group date datepicker'>
                        <form:input type='text' class="form-control" path="requestDate" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">${labelSurveyRequestSurveyDate}</label>
                    <div class='col-md-3 input-group date datepicker'>
                        <form:input type='text' class="form-control" path="surveyPlanDate" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>       

                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
                        path="surveyPlanTime">${labelSurveyRequestSurveyTime}</form:label>
                    <div class='col-md-3 input-group date timepicker'>
                        <form:input type='text' class="form-control" path="surveyPlanTime" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                        </span>                         
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="form-group">        
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">${labelSurveyRequestHectarage}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hectarage" />
                    </div>
                </div>                      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="col-md-3"></p>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${surveyRequest.priority == true}">
                                ${labelSurveyRequestPriority}
                            </c:when>
                        </c:choose>      
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="col-md-3"></p>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>${labelSurveyRequestNorth}</th>
                                    <th>${labelSurveyRequestEast}</th>
                                    <th>${labelSurveyRequestSouth}</th>
                                    <th>${labelSurveyRequestWest}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${surveyRequest.borderNorth}</td>
                                    <td>${surveyRequest.borderEast}</td>
                                    <td>${surveyRequest.borderSouth}</td>
                                    <td>${surveyRequest.borderWest}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>         
                    </div>
                </div>  

            </form:form>
        </c:if>
    </div>  
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {         
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false,
            language: 'id',             
        });
        $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
            pickDate: false,
            minuteStepping:15,
            useSeconds: false,
            language: 'id'
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/surveyrequest")
@Controller
public class SurveyRequestController {
private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(SurveyRequestController.class);

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
private SurveyRequestService surveyRequestService;  

// Others code omitted

@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, Model model) {
    SurveyRequest request = surveyRequestService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("surveyRequest", request);
    return "surveyrequest/show";
}

/*
 * Edit a survey request
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", params="form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateForm(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, Model model) {
    SurveyRequest request = surveyRequestService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("surveyRequest", request);
    return "surveyrequest/edit";
}
/*
 * Update a survey request
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(SurveyRequest surveyRequest, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, 
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("surveyrequest_save_fail", new Object[]{}, locale)));         
        uiModel.addAttribute("surveyRequest", surveyRequest);
        return "surveyrequest/update";
    }
    uiModel.asMap().clear();
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("surveyrequest_save_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));        
    logger.info("Before paste: " + surveyRequest);
    surveyRequestService.save(surveyRequest);

    return "redirect:/surveyrequest/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(surveyRequest.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
}
```

**Updated**:
I could resolve the problem with removing enctype="multipart/form-data" at edit.jspx. But it raised another issue, how if I'm going to upload file?

Comment: For a file upload, you'll need a `CommonsMultipartResolver` in your application context plus some supporting jars in order for Spring to bind the request parameters. Without this, Spring won't understand how to bind the form data to the model (you'll see null values). [This article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/) walks through what you'll need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@ModelAttribute` annotation to your model object parameter in the controller method that you're calling, so that Spring knows that's the object that you want to bind the form data to.

```
/*
 * Update a survey request
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("surveyRequest") SurveyRequest surveyRequest,
                     BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel,
                     HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                     RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale) {
  [...]
}
```

Comment: No result by adding @ModelAttribute. I think Spring already bind form data with object. As my database record were updated (but with null value).